# Mount Physical device to Notebook

Tags: python, mount, mtp, umount

I need to mount by phone (Huawei Honor 6) to the notebook.
This is the python code, what I wrote : (python phonedirectory.py)

```
import os

os.getcwd()
os.chdir("/media/")
os.system("killall gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor")
os.system("killall gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor")

dir = os.path.dirname("karthik/")

if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.system("sudo mkdir karthik")

os.getcwd()

os.system("sudo chmod 777 karthik")

os.system("sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/karthik")

os.system("ls")

print('LIST OF FILES:')

os.system("ls /media/karthik/SD\ card/Bluetooth")

print('TOTAL NUMBER OF FILES:')

os.system("ls /media/karthik/SD\ card/Bluetooth | wc -l")

os.system("sudo umount karthik")

os.system("sudo rmdir karthik")
```

This is the error what I got :

```
Listing raw device(s)
mtpfs: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9: undefined symbol: usb_init
```

till this command `os.system("sudo chmod 777 karthik")` it works fine..
After that, I am getting the error..

Executing this :

```
mtp-detect | grep idVendor
mtp-detect | grep idProduct
```

Results in this :

```
karthik@dkarnik2-Vostro-3558:~$ mtp-detect | grep idVendor
mtp-detect: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9: undefined symbol: usb_init
karthik@dkarnik2-Vostro-3558:~$ mtp-detect | grep idProduct
mtp-detect: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9: undefined symbol: usb_init
```

executing `mtp-detect` gives me this :

```
libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
mtp-detect: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9: undefined symbol: usb_init
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04

Someone please tell me how to resolve that error..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system misses some library, maybe libusb or something similar?

I'm not 100% about this, try this:

```
sudo apt-get intsall libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope you can tell me exactly what is missing.

Comment: `libusb-1.0-0 is already the newest version.`
`libusb-1.0-0-dev is already the newest version.`
`libusb-1.0-0-dev set to manually installed.`
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 647 not upgraded.`

Comment: Have you installed libmtp (or mtp-tools) with apt?

Comment: mtp-tools is installed.. while trying to install libmtp, i get this: karthik@dkarnik2-Vostro-3558:~$ sudo apt-get install libmtp
`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree `      
`Reading state information... Done`
`E: Unable to locate package libmtp`

Comment: Sorry I just wanted to ask: where does your mtplib come from? have you installed it with apt or did you install it otherwise? I ask because in your question the error says '/usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9', that's not the directory of the library if you install it with apt. If not with apt: try to install the mtp-tools package.

Comment: I don't remember what way i installed it.. Should i uninstall it and install back again using apt ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just using this command `mv /usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9 /usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9_backUp`
and then try using `mtp-detect`. Reason of this stupidity could be `/usr/local/lib/libmtp.so.9` this library might not be compatible with your version. Instead of removing we better keep it's backup so that if that doesn't work you can rollback this workaround.